# Console error on import of non-existent file in vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vite, dynamic-import

I am migrating from webpack using Vue2.7 and @vitejs/plugin-vue2.
So there was one problem.

```js
await import(`${path}/${config || 'config'}`).catch(e => ({default: {}}))).default
```

Up to now, when the above code was executed, if the imported file was missing, the console would not display an error and it would be handled properly.

But when I move to vite, once I do import, I get a Not Found error and then run catch.
like this.

```
http://localhost:14400/src/User/config net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Does vite have a way to handle a missing file without displaying an error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

By default imports in rollup (Vite's bundler) are hoisted (put on the top of the file ignoring try/catch) so you need to pass rollup options to override the default behavior as described here:

https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#ignoretrycatch

commonjs options can be configured in Vite's config file in the build section:

https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-commonjsoptions

Comment: Thank you! However, I still get the same error. Do I need to put in any plugins or anything else?

Comment: Perhaps this option is something that does not work on a local server? I have not been able to test it as I do not have a production environment yet.